# Test POST method to send the file content

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, htmlunit

I have a method in Controller which takes the MultipartFile(Spring class )object as and stores it. I have to do an integration test. 
So when the user logs in , it should be able to upload a file. I am using htmlUnit Webresponse class to send the request to controller @localhost. 
how can i add the Multipartfile object to Webresponse or is there some other way to test it ?

Thanks
Harshit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
MultipartPostMethod method =
        new MultipartPostMethod( "http://localhost:8080/sendfile" );
                   method.addParameter("mediaFile", multifile );
   HttpClient client1 = new HttpClient( );
// Execute and print response
    client1.executeMethod( method );
    String response = method.getResponseBodyAsString( );
    System.out.println( response );
    method.releaseConnection( );
    return response;
```

The class is part of apache-httpclient jar